# Após cadastro (em PDO), direcionar a página para o index.html

Tags: php, html, pdo

Estou utilizando HTML e PHP. A conexão com o banco funciona, ele cadastra os dados inseridos e tudo mais. Na sequência, eu abro o index.html, nele tem a opção que me leva à página de cadastro:

```
<li><a href="http://localhost/middleearth/form-add.php">REGISTRAR</a></li>
```

Este form-add.php me apresenta o formulário e cadastro e, num arquivo chamado add.php, eu abro a conexão para inserção no banco. Neste mesmo add.php, eu tenho:

```
header('Location: register_ok.php');
```

Este register_ok.php informa que o cadastro foi realizado com êxito e dá o link para voltar a index.html:

```
<div id="options" class="container text-center">
<h2>CADASTRO</h2>
<p>Cadastro efetuado com sucesso! </p>
<a href="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/middleearth/personagens.html">Ir para a Tela Inicial</a>
<br>
```

É aí que mora meu problema. Sei que pode ser algo muito besta de resolver, mas eu simplesmente não consigo direcionar ele de volta pro index.html pra que ele volte a home e solicite o login. Eu clico no link e ele não abre. Já tentei usar o *header* também e nada. A questão é, arquivos .php acessados pelo localhost/*pasta do projeto* parecem não aceitar esse direcionamento para arquivos em .html. Alguém pode me dar uma força?

Comment: `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/middleearth/personagens.html`? Não seria `http://localhost/middleearth/`

Comment: Eu tentei com "http://localhost/middleearth/" também. Mas ele abre a página .html sem as imagens que têm originalmente nela e, os links dela não funcionam.

Comment: Pode printar e [inserir na pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/192621/edit)? Esta realmente difícil de enxergar o que acontece

Comment: Ele deveria aparecer assim: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AgqAaYt29G0Iw3T9z97BCJehrTXt

Mas colocando o localhost/middleearth ele aparece assim:
https://1drv.ms/i/s!AgqAaYt29G0Iw3O3WAvk0xBqjgPA

Comment: Vinicius, juro que essas imagens não ajudaram em muita coisa a entender o que realmente esta acontecendo rs debug no console e veja qual o erro

Comment: **Provavelmente** as imagens só não estão sendo carregadas por que o path do localhost é criado(e gerenciado) por uma rota no xampp, se você corrigir no index.html isso sera corrigido também, só que isso fica no achismo, por que não esta muito claro ;/

Comment: Cara isso parece ser somente os caminhos das imagens, teria como postar o codigo? ficaria mais fácil para ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Faz o seguinte:

Verifica o fluxo da tua aplicação, talvez não estejam carregando porque o fluxo ao ser solicitada a página, ela não tá passando por algum script que era pra ela ter passado.

Não usa esse `header('location'...)`, se for pra chamar alguma página, usa um `require("register_ok.php")`

Quando você for utilizar o `header()`, certifique-se de que não tenha sido enviada nenhuma saída ainda.